# Check Type: How to check if something is a RDD or a DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm using Python, and this is a Spark RDD / DataFrame.

I tried `isinstance(thing, RDD)` but `RDD` wasn't recognized.

The reason I need to do this:

I'm writing a function where both `RDD` and `DataFrame` could be passed in, so I'll need to do `input.rdd` to get the underlying RDD if a DataFrame is passed in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`isinstance` will work just fine:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.rdd import RDD

def foo(x):
    if isinstance(x, RDD):
        return "RDD"
    if isinstance(x, DataFrame):
        return "DataFrame"

foo(sc.parallelize([]))
## 'RDD'
foo(sc.parallelize([("foo", 1)]).toDF())
## 'DataFrame'
```

but single dispatch is much more elegant approach:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def bar(x):
    pass 

@bar.register(RDD)
def _(arg):
    return "RDD"

@bar.register(DataFrame)
def _(arg):
    return "DataFrame"

bar(sc.parallelize([]))
## 'RDD'

bar(sc.parallelize([("foo", 1)]).toDF())
## 'DataFrame'
```

If you don't mind additional dependencies [`multipledispatch`](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch/) is also an interesting option:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(RDD)
def baz(x):
    return "RDD"

@dispatch(DataFrame)
def baz(x):
    return "DataFrame"

baz(sc.parallelize([]))
## 'RDD'

baz(sc.parallelize([("foo", 1)]).toDF())
## 'DataFrame'
```

Finally the most Pythonic approach is to simply check an interface:

```
def foobar(x):
    if hasattr(x, "rdd"):
        ## It is a DataFrame
    else:
        ## It (probably) is a RDD
```

Answer (score 18):

another way to check is type

```
type(object)
```

that return the type of the object like

```
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

Answer (score -1):

In the body of your function you can have an assignment checking the instance of `input`

```py
from pyspark.rdd import RDD

def compute(input):
  your_rdd = input if isinstance(input, RDD) else input.rdd()
```